# Xamarin android fill listview async with progressbar

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, android-asynctask, xamarin.android

How to fill a `ListView` async in Xamarin.Android on the activity's onCreate?
I know how to call an async method upon button click and add a progress bar, but how to do the same with the onCreate method?
What I need is to open the activity and show a progressbar while a list of 20.000 items is loading.

In Eclipse Java I used to call the `AsyncTask` (onpreexecute ... doinbackgroud ...onpostexecute) but in Xamarin I can't figure out how to do this.
Any help or tutorial on this?

I tried this way by using the method that @Yuri provided but still not working:

```
 async protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.PulledItemsList);
        ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ActionBar.Title = "Catalog";
        _activity = this;

        //display your activity indicator and start spin
        ProgressDialog progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressdialog.SetCancelable(false);
        progressdialog.Indeterminate = true;
        progressdialog.SetMessage("Loading...");
        progressdialog.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Spinner);
        progressdialog.Show();
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            fillListView();
        })
           .ContinueWith((t) =>
         {
             RunOnUiThread(() =>
                        {
                            progressdialog.Hide();
                            progressdialog.Dismiss();
                        });
         });
 }
```

and this method:

```
 async protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.PulledItemsList);
        ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ActionBar.Title = "Catalog";
        _activity = this;
        //display your activity indicator and start spin
        ProgressDialog progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressdialog.SetCancelable(false);
        progressdialog.Indeterminate = true;
        progressdialog.SetMessage("Loading...");
        progressdialog.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Spinner);
        progressdialog.Show();

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
              fillListView();
            });
        });

         progressdialog.Hide();
         progressdialog.Dismiss();

        //disable indicator, list loaded
    }
```

and fillListView() function is :

```
 private void fillListView()
    {
        var listview = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listview);
        List<oneimg_twolbl> ItemObjectList = new List<oneimg_twolbl>();
        oneimg_twolbl ItemObject = new oneimg_twolbl(0, "", "");
        List<Items> Itemlist = Items.SelectFromItems();
        if (Itemlist.Count == 0)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, GetString(Resource.String.NoItems), ToastLength.Long);
        }
        foreach (Items current_item in Itemlist)
        {
            ItemObject = new oneimg_twolbl(Resource.Drawable.StockQty, current_item.ItemBarcode.ToString().Trim(), current_item.DisplayField.ToString().Trim(), current_item.ItemNum);
            ItemObjectList.Add(ItemObject);
        }
        adapter = new PulledItemList_Adapter(this, ItemObjectList);
        listview.Adapter = adapter;


        listview.ItemClick += delegate (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs args)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(ManageItemsActivity));
            oneimg_twolbl clicked_Item = adapter.GetItem_bypos(args.Position);
            Items selected_Item = Items.SelectWhereFromItems(clicked_Item.Id);
            i.PutExtra("parameter1", ManageItemsActivity.EDITMODE);
            i.PutExtra("parameter2", selected_Item.ItemCode);
            i.PutExtra("parameter3", selected_Item.ItemNum);
            i.PutExtra("Displayfield", selected_Item.DisplayField);
            StartActivity(i);
        };
    }
```

adapter class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace SocrateMobile.Droid.Adapter
{
class PulledItemList_Adapter : BaseAdapter<oneimg_twolbl>
{
    private Activity context;
    private List<oneimg_twolbl> AllItemList;


    public PulledItemList_Adapter(Activity context, List<oneimg_twolbl> AllItemList)
    {
        this.AllItemList = AllItemList;
        this.context = context;
    }
    public oneimg_twolbl GetItem_bypos(int position)
    {
        return AllItemList[position];
    }
    public override oneimg_twolbl this[int position]
    {
        get { return AllItemList[position]; }
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return AllItemList.Count; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        Holder_oneimg_twolbl holder = null;
        var view = convertView;

        if (view != null)
            holder = view.Tag as Holder_oneimg_twolbl;


        if (holder == null)
        {
            holder = new Holder_oneimg_twolbl();
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.oneimg_twolbl, null);
            holder.Text = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text_list4_view);
            holder.Text2 = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text_list4_view2);
            holder.Image = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.image_list4_view);
            view.Tag = holder;
        }

        var current_item = AllItemList[position];


        holder.Text.Text = current_item.FirstTxt;
        holder.Text2.Text = current_item.SecondTxt;
        holder.Image.SetImageResource(current_item.FirstImg);
        holder.holderId = current_item.Id;

        if (!holder.Image.HasOnClickListeners)
        {
            holder.Image.Click += delegate
            {
                PulledItemListActivity Itemlistactivity = new                PulledItemListActivity();
                Itemlistactivity.QtyImageClick(holder.holderId);
            };
        }

        return view;
    }



    public class Holder_oneimg_twolbl : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        public TextView Text { get; set; }
        public TextView Text2 { get; set; }
        public ImageView Image { get; set; }

        public int holderId { get; set; }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code here is how to do what you need:

In OnCreate call

```
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            fillListView();
        });
```

You fill listview function will look like below. I had to comment out some of your code and added Delay for testing. You can restore your code but keep in mind that you need to set up adapter BEFORE you put object to it. Then it will update your screen while spinner is working. If you don't need that then you don't have to call NotifyDataSetChanges.

```
private void fillListView()
        {
            var listview = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
            List<oneimg_twolbl> ItemObjectList = new List<oneimg_twolbl>();



            //oneimg_twolbl ItemObject = new oneimg_twolbl(0, "", "");

            //List<Items> Itemlist = Items.SelectFromItems();
            //if (Itemlist.Count == 0)
            //{
            //    Toast.MakeText(this, "No items", ToastLength.Long);
            //}
            //foreach (Items current_item in Itemlist)
            //{
            //    ItemObject = new oneimg_twolbl(Resource.Drawable.Icon, current_item.ItemBarcode.ToString().Trim(), current_item.DisplayField.ToString().Trim(), current_item.ItemNum);
            //    ItemObjectList.Add(ItemObject);
            //}

            var adapter = new PulledItemList_Adapter(this, ItemObjectList);
            listview.Adapter = adapter;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {
                    ItemObjectList.Add(new oneimg_twolbl(i, i.ToString(), i.ToString()));
                    adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
                }); 
                Task.Delay(500).Wait();
            }



            listview.ItemClick += delegate (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs args)
            {
                //Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(ManageItemsActivity));
                //oneimg_twolbl clicked_Item = adapter.GetItem_bypos(args.Position);
                //Items selected_Item = Items.SelectWhereFromItems(clicked_Item.Id);
                //i.PutExtra("parameter1", ManageItemsActivity.EDITMODE);
                //i.PutExtra("parameter2", selected_Item.ItemCode);
                //i.PutExtra("parameter3", selected_Item.ItemNum);
                //i.PutExtra("Displayfield", selected_Item.DisplayField);
                //StartActivity(i);
            };
        }
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your method. the first one gives me an exception when i try to fill the list : **Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.**  And the second one where I have RunOnUiThread I filled the list in task.run and dismiss the progress in RunOnUiThread it seams that it works but I can't see any row(the list is not filled) and  when I click back or open a new activity I am getting an exception: **Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: The observer is null.**

Comment: For the first method you should also use RunOnUiThread(()=> around code where you fill the list. The sedcond should give you the same exception because it also is not protected by RunOnUiThread so I assume you put your list filling code inside ContinueWith which is wrong, It should be inside Task.Run and only dismiss should be in ContinueWith. I updated my answer. Regarding to null observer or something - This is not related to the code I provided. Check your filling and binding code

Comment: if you provide sample solution I might be able to help more

Comment: any progress on this?

Comment: Hello @Yuri Sorry for being late. when I added RunOnUiThread to the first method It showed it did not worked... It shows a black screen before loading the list. the second method i show the progress but still I cant see the list. I will update my question and add both code cases

Comment: Have you tried to fill the list without using progress dialog synchronously?To be able to help I need also code of PulledItemList_Adapter, your activity xml (PulledItemsList), definition of "oneimg_twolbl" and Items (Items.SelectFromItems). The best is to share a complete sample solution

Comment: first the list is showed correctly without using progress dialog asynchronously. Second I can pass the adapter code. the activity xml contain a list view with two button at the bottom. oneimg_twolbl is an object that contain one int(image src id) and 2 strings. Item.selectFromItems function that query the sqlite and select the list Items from the databse .

Comment: OK thank you for your help the last update to the answer worked :) but I needed to set up the adapter before the fillList function and that worked. Thank you again for your help and time